# MSSQL -> MySQL or PostgreSQL DB replication

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, postgresql, database-replication

I find myself in a situation that someone else must have got stuck in at some point.

Our company runs an in house MSSQL based database, our website then sits on an external server and currently runs MySQL.  The problem comes that both databases need to communicate with each other increasingly often.

Our current solution involves SSIS packages but they are tempromental and often slow.  We end up very often having to drop tables on our live production server before then rebuilding them from the in house server.  Of course this is leading to data inconsistencies so we try and perform these operations outside of peak hours.  However, this leads to 24hr delays in some data being transferred from MySQL to MSSQL and then an additional 24hr delay in getting it back to MySQL.  None of this is ideal.

What I am looking for is a solution that will allow replication between our in-house MSSQL server and any database that can sit upon a linux box and play nicely with PHP.  As I said, we currently run MySQL so we have a preference to any solution that would include that but all other suggestions would be greatfully received.

I've read somewhere that PostgreSQL is a vialbe solution but I am now struggling to find where I read that.  I've come accross a few tools that might help such as DBMoto and Slony-I, does anyone have any experience of either in such a situation?

Alternatively, are we simply barking up the wrong tree altogether and should we be trying to integrate MSSQL into our PHP environment?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be gratefully recieved.

Many thanks

Rob

Comment: the information you provide is not enough to help... any bidirectional replication between two different DB is bound to have some problems... some result from differences in the DB, some from available replication option... any reason you don't use the same for both (MSSQL for both OR Postgresql for both OR Oracle for both...) ?

Comment: MSSQL+MySQL is the status quo here.  We don't have the option to change the in-house database but I would happily investigate the option of changing our web server to MSSQL if this is what you suggest.  I see that PHP and MSSQL talk relatively happy but would installing MSSQL on CentOS require some virtualisation solution?

Comment: MSSQL will need a Windows server... PHP can run on Windows too... so one option is switch to a Windows web server with MSSQL...

Comment: While I guess that is an option, I'd like to only use that as a final last resort.  We're rather happy with our linux server at the moment and switching to a windows server would be a big upheaval.

Comment: then I wish you luck that someone can give you a production-quality answer for your scenario...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution that i know and i have used for this kind of job is [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/) .

> SymmetricDS is an asynchronous data replication software package that
>   supports multiple subscribers and bi-directional synchronization.

Comment: Looks like a good option, is it pretty easy to set up and configure?

Comment: It is not too complicated to configure and there is a good documentation on the official site.

Comment: I've just noted that its compatability is limited to SQL Sever 2005, we run 2008 R2, any idea if that is likely to be compatable too?

Comment: I've used it also with SQL Server 2008 R2 with JTDS JDBC Driver .

Comment: Thanks, aleroot.  I'll be testing this in earnest next week.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can access MSSQL servers from PHP using FreeTDS and the mssql_* family of functions (or classes built thereon, or alternative freetds-using extensions). We use this for our admin application, with a Linux/PHP website talking to a MSSQL database.

Comment: I came accross the mssql_* family of functions but as the two servers are geographically remote, I fear that the latency between the two would cause significant issues.  Is this true for your setup too?

Comment: No, our web server and database server are close together. (we do some communications over the longer distance from office to prod, but not as often, and latency does show up). But if you're already handling a mssql<->mysql replication over a slow link, a mssql<->mssql replication should be less troublesome? although I believe that will only work in a single-master mode.